# LCP with sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

*I indicate matrices by capital letters, and vectors by small letters.*

I need to solve the following system of linear inequalities for vector `v`:

```
min(rv - (u + Av), v - s) = 0
```

where `0` is a vector of zeros.

where `r` is a scalar, `u` and `s` are vectors, and `A` is a matrix.

Defining `z = v-s`, `B=rI - A`, `q=-u + Bs`, I can rewrite the previous problem as a [linear complementarity problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complementarity_problem) and hope to use an LCP solver, for example from `openopt`:

```
LCP(M, z): min(Bz+q, z) = 0
```

or, in matrix notation:

```
z'(Bz+q) = 0
z >= 0
Bz + q >= 0
```

---

The problem is that my system of equations is huge. To create `A`, I

- Create four matrices `A11`, `A12`, `A21`, `A22` using `scipy.sparse.diags`
- And stack them together as `A = scipy.sparse.bmat([[A11, A12], [A21, A22]])`
- (This also means that `A` is not symmetric, and hence some efficient translations into `QP` problems won't work)

`openopt.LCP` apparently cannot deal with sparse matrices: When I ran this, my computer crashed. Generally, `A.todense()` will lead to a memory error. Similarly, `compecon-python` is not able to solve `LCP` problems with sparse matrices.

What alternative `LCP` implementations are fit for this problem?

---

I really did not think *sample data* was required for a general "which tools to solve LCP" question were required, but anyways, here we go

```
from numpy.random import rand
from scipy import sparse

n = 3000
r = 0.03

A = sparse.diags([-rand(n)], [0])
s = rand(n,).reshape((-1, 1))
u = rand(n,).reshape((-1, 1))

B = sparse.eye(n)*r - A
q = -u + B.dot(s)

q.shape
Out[37]: (3000, 1)
B
Out[38]: 
<3000x3000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

---

Some more pointers:

- `openopt.LCP` crashes with my matrices, I assume it converts the matrices to dense before continuing
- `compecon-python` outright fails with some error, it apparently requires dense matrices and has no fallback for sparsity
- `B` is not positive semi-definite, so I cannot rephrase the linear complementarity problem (LCP) as a convex quadratic problem (QP)
- All QP sparse solvers from [this exposition](https://github.com/stephane-caron/qpsolvers) require the problem to be convex, which mine is not
- In Julia, [PATHSolver](https://github.com/JuliaPy/pyjulia) can solve my problem (given a license). However, there are problems calling it from Python with [PyJulia](https://github.com/JuliaPy/pyjulia) ([my issue report here](https://github.com/JuliaPy/pyjulia/issues/123))
- Also Matlab has an LCP solver that apparently can handle sparse matrices, but there implementation is even more wacky (and I really do not want to fallback on Matlab for this)

Comment: There's a collection of solvers that came with `scipy.sparse`.  They are built around the idea of linear operator, something with a matrix vector product, `A*v` .  Anything that assumes more about the matrix is likely to have problems with a sparse matrix.  It has to explicitly say it works with `scipy.sparse` (and which format).

Comment: openopt/openopt/kernel/nonOptMisc.py has code that deals with scipy.sparse matrices.

Comment: @hpaulj not sure what to make of your second comment - the `LCP` methods I found at `openopt` appeared not to work - what exactly can I do with `nonOptMisc`?

Comment: What does "appeared not to work" mean, specifically? Can you expand on the "apparently" part of "openopt.LCP apparently cannot deal with sparse matrices"? What caused the crash?

Comment: @FooBar you need to provide sample input data, you did not even specify the size of your matrices. Anyway try cvxpy instead of OpenOpt or even better try scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html

Comment: @denfromufa I did have a look at `cvxpy`, it did not have a direct way of solving LCPs. I tried to rephrase my problem as a QP and solve that with cvxpy's QP solver, but my `B` is not p.s.d. - the resulting problem is not  convex and cannot be solved with standard convex solution methods.

Comment: @denfromufa Regarding `scipy.linprob`, it's not clear to me how to rewrite the problem into the form required for `linprob` to work - apparently that also requires `B` to be positive semi definite?

Comment: @FooBar have you tried these 2 sparse matrix least square solvers from scipy?https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr

Comment: @denfromufa These least square solvers solve linear systems of equations, they minimize `abs(Ax-b)`. I don't think it is possible to rewrite an LCP (added wikipedia link to question) into a way that these solvers can make use of

Comment: Apparently you can use Pyomo with PATH solver, since the latter supports AMPL format and Pyomo output that by default. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36809878/2230844

Comment: The problem (matrix-form) can be solved by scipy.optimize, which is fast for n=300, but slow for n=3000. You probably should have added more information, e.g. links to all those solvers you tried. Maybe the matlab-one for example is easily ported (and made more robust).

Comment: Give it a try https://github.com/troyshu/openopt

Comment: 1
down vote
 

Use SUMT by Stephen Boyd. I've used it before for linear systems that have <= or >= constraints and it works very well.

SUMT = Sequential Uncontrained Minimisation Techique.

Comment: I wonder if Octave offers anything suitable for you (since Matlab does).

Comment: *Defining ..., I can rewrite the previous problem as a linear complementarity problem* Do you realize that adding the extra constraint `z'(Bz+q) = 0` makes it a different problem?

Comment: @Leon Indeed I was a bit sloppy in writing the original problem, that should be fixed now.

Comment: @Leon raises a key point that needs clarification; the actual problem statement is ambiguous.  When you write the original problem `min(rv - (u + Av), v - s) = 0` what specifically do you mean: (a) min_v (rv - u - Av).dot(v-s) (as in minimizing a quadratic form); (b) find v such that (min_v (rv - u - Av).dot(v-s)) == 0; or (c/d) either of the two above but elementwise (as in, not the inner product .dot, but an elementwise minimum, so 0 is a vector of zeros?  All of those have different answers; some fairly nice (some not so nice).

Comment: @muskrat The latter, 0 is a vector. For each point, either the left argument is zero and the right argument is non-negative or the left argument is non-negative and the right argument is zero.

Answer (score 4):

This problem has a very efficient (linear time) solution, though it requires a bit of discussion...

**Zeroth: clarifying the problem / LCP**

Per clarifications in the comments, @FooBar says the original problem is elementwise `min`; we need to find a `z` (or `v`) such that

> either the left argument is zero and the right argument is non-negative or the left argument is non-negative and the right argument is zero

As @FooBar correctly points out, a valid reparameterization leads to an LCP.  However, below I show that an easier and more efficient solution to the original problem can be achieved (by exploiting structure in the original problem) without needing the LCP.  Why should this be easier?  Well, notice that an LCP has a quadratic term in `z` (Bz+q)'z, but that the original problem doesn't (only linear terms Bz+q and z).  I'll exploit that fact below.

**First: simplify**

There is an important but key detail that simplifies this problem in a major way:

> - Create four matrices A11, A12, A21, A22 using scipy.sparse.diags
> - And
>     stack them together as A = scipy.sparse.bmat([[A11, A12], [A21,
>     A22]])

This has huge implications.  Specifically, this is not a **single** **large** problem, but rather a **large number** of **really small** (2D, to be precise) problems.  Notice that the block diagonal structure of this `A` matrix is preserved throughout all subsequent operations.  And every subsequent operation is a matrix-vector multiply or an inner product.  This means that really this program is *separable* in pairs of `z` (or `v`) variables.

To be specific, suppose each block `A11,...` is size `n` by `n`. Then notice critically that `z_1` and `z_{n+1}` appear **only** in equations and terms with themselves, and never elsewhere.  So the problem is separable into `n` problems, each of which is 2 dimensional.  Thus, I will hereafter solve the 2D problem, and you can serialize or parallelize over `n` as you see fit, without sparse matrices or big opt packages.

**Second: the geometry of the 2D problem**

Assume we have the elementwise problem in 2D, namely:

```
find z such that (elementwise) min( Bz + q , z ) = 0, or declare that no such `z` exists.
```

Because in our setup `B` is now 2x2, this problem geometry corresponds to four scalar inequalities that we can manually enumerate (I’ve named them a1,a2,z1,z2):

```
“a1”: B11*z1 + B12*z2 + q1 >=0
“a2”: B21*z1 + B22*z2 + q2 >=0
“z1”: z1 >= 0
“z2:” z2 >= 0
```

This represents a (possibly empty) polyhedra, aka the intersection of four half spaces in 2d space.

**Third: solving the 2D problem**

(Edit: updated this bit for clarity)

What specifically is the 2D problem then?  We want to find a `z` where one of the following solutions (which are not all distinct, but that won’t matter) is achieved:

1. a1>=0, z1=0, a2>=0, z2=0
2. a1=0, z1>=0, a2=0, z2>=0
3. a1>=0, z1=0, a2=0, z2>=0
4. a1=0, z1>=0, a2>=0, z2=0

If one of these is achieved, we have a solution: a z where the elementwise minimum of z and Bz+q is the 0 vector.  If none of the four can be achieved, the problem is infeasible and we will declare that no such `z` exists.

The first case occurs when the intersection point of a1,a2 is in the positive orthant.  Just choose the solution z = B^-1q, and check if it is elementwise nonnegative.  If it is, return `B^-1q` (note that, even though B is not psd, I am assuming it is invertible/full rank).  So:

```
if B^-1q is elementwise nonnegative, return z = B^-1q.
```

The second case (not entirely distinct from the first) occurs when the intersection point of a1,a2 is anywhere but does contain the origin.  In otherwords, whenever Bz+q >0 for z = 0.  This occurs when q is elementwise positive.  So:

```
elif q is elementwise nonnegative, return z = 0.
```

The third case has z1=0, which can be substituted into a2 to show that a2=0 when z2 = -q2/B22.  z2 must be >=0, so -q2/B22 >=0.  a1 must also be >=0, which substituting in the values for z1 and z2, gives -B22/B12*q2 + q1 >=0.  So:

```
elif -q2/B22 >=0 and  -B22/B12*q2 + q1 >=0, return z1= 0, z2 = -q2/B22.
```

The fourth step is the same as the third, but swapping 1 and 2.  So:

```
elif -q1/B11 >=0 and -B21/B11*q1 + q2 >=0, return z1 = -q1/B11, z2 =0.
```

The final fifth case is when the problem is infeasible.  That occurs when none of the above conditions are met.  So:

```
else return None
```

**Finally: put the pieces together**

Solving each 2D problem is a couple of simple/efficient/trivial linear solves and compares. Each will return a pair of numbers or `None`. Then just do same over all `n` 2D problems, and concatenate the vector.  If any are None, the problem is infeasible (all None).  Else, you have your answer.

Comment: I've not claimed for the initial problem `min(...)` to be an LCP. Indeed, only the reformulation is an LCP. Regarding PSD `B`, from wikipedia: "*If M is positive definite, any algorithm for solving (strictly) convex QPs can solve the LCP.*". I take that statement implicitely to mean that LCP really does **not** rely on `B` being PSD.

Comment: I totally agree; I didn’t mean to imply you claimed that. What I mean is the original problem can be solved extremely efficiently without having to worry about lcp.  And to the second point yes you’re right lcp need not be a psd M, but what I meant was that many solution approaches rely on M being psd.

Comment: @FooBar I edited the LCP part of my answer to correct my statement from before; thanks for pointing out, hopefully this clarifies.

Comment: I'm trying to go really slow here as to not miss something, so excuse all the "quibbles". Next, I'm not sure I understand how stacking 4 `A11,...` matrices makes `A` a *block diagonal* matrix?

Comment: Is there any reason to test the difference cases in this specific order? Otherwise I would suggest testing last for the first case, as it requires the inverse of the matrix. Sure, it's only a 2x2 matrix, but if it's possible, I don't see a reason not to do it that way. Particularly the second case would be much faster to test for.

Comment: Furthermore, if the matrix was to not be invertible, could the other cases still yield valid solutions?

Answer (score 0):

#### LCP solver for Python based on AMPLPY

as @denfromufa pointed out, there's an `AMPL` interface to the `PATH` solver. He suggested `Pyomo` since it's open source and able to process `AMPL`. However, `Pyomo` turned out to be slow and tedious to work with. I have ultimately written my own interface to the `PATH` solver in cython and hope to release that at some point, but at this moment it has no input sanitation, is quick and dirty and I don't see the time of working on it.

For now, I can share an answer that uses the python extension of `AMPL`. It's not as fast as a direct interface to `PATH`: For every `LCP` we want to solve, it creates a (temporary) model file, runs `AMPL`, and collects the output. It's somewhat quick and dirty, but I felt that I should at least report parts of the results of the several past months since asking this question.

```
import os
# PATH license string needs to be updated
os.environ['PATH_LICENSE_STRING'] = "3413119131&Courtesy&&&USR&54784&12_1_2016&1000&PATH&GEN&31_12_2017&0_0_0&5000&0_0"


from amplpy import AMPL, Environment, dataframe
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from tempfile import mkstemp
import os

import sys
import contextlib

class DummyFile(object):
    def write(self, x): pass

@contextlib.contextmanager
def nostdout():
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = DummyFile()
    yield
    sys.stdout = save_stdout


class modFile:
    # context manager: create temporary file, insert model data, and supply file name
    # apparently, amplpy coders are inable to support StringIO

    content = """
        set Rn;


        param B {Rn,Rn} default 0;
        param q {Rn} default 0;

        var x {j in Rn};

        s.t. f {i in Rn}:
                0 <= x[i]
             complements
                sum {j in Rn} B[i,j]*x[j]
                 >= -q[i];
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.fd = None
        self.temp_path = None

    def __enter__(self):
        fd, temp_path = mkstemp()
        file = open(temp_path, 'r+')
        file.write(self.content)
        file.close()

        self.fd = fd
        self.temp_path = temp_path
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        os.close(self.fd)
        os.remove(self.temp_path)


def solveLCP(B, q, x=None, env=None, binaryDirectory=None, pathOptions={'logfile':'logpath.tmp' }, verbose=False):
    # x: initial guess
    if binaryDirectory is not None:
        env = Environment(binaryDirectory='/home/foo/amplide.linux64/')
    if verbose:
        pathOptions['output'] = 'yes'
    ampl = AMPL(environment=env)

    # read model
    with modFile() as mod:
        ampl.read(mod.temp_path)

    n = len(q)
    # prepare dataframes
    dfQ = dataframe.DataFrame('Rn', 'c')
    for i in np.arange(n):
        # shitty amplpy does not support np.float
        dfQ.addRow(int(i)+1, np.float(q[i]))

    dfB = dataframe.DataFrame(('RnRow', 'RnCol'), 'val')

    if sparse.issparse(B):
        if not isinstance(B, sparse.lil_matrix):
            B = B.tolil()
        dfB.setValues({
            (i+1, j+1): B.data[i][jPos]
            for i, row in enumerate(B.rows)
            for jPos, j in enumerate(row)
            })

    else:
        r = np.arange(n) + 1
        Rrow, Rcol = np.meshgrid(r, r, indexing='ij')
        #dfB.setColumn('RnRow', [np.float(x) for x in Rrow.reshape((-1), order='C')])
        dfB.setColumn('RnRow', list(Rrow.reshape((-1), order='C').astype(float)))
        dfB.setColumn('RnCol', list(Rcol.reshape((-1), order='C').astype(float)))
        dfB.setColumn('val', list(B.reshape((-1), order='C').astype(float)))

    # set values
    ampl.getSet('Rn').setValues([int(x) for x in np.arange(n, dtype=int)+1])
    if x is not None:
        dfX = dataframe.DataFrame('Rn', 'x')
        for i in np.arange(n):
            # shitty amplpy does not support np.float
            dfX.addRow(int(i)+1, np.float(x[i]))
        ampl.getVariable('x').setValues(dfX)

    ampl.getParameter('q').setValues(dfQ)
    ampl.getParameter('B').setValues(dfB)

    # solve
    ampl.setOption('solver', 'pathampl')

    pathOptions = ['{}={}'.format(key, val) for key, val in pathOptions.items()]
    ampl.setOption('path_options', ' '.join(pathOptions))
    if verbose:
        ampl.solve()
    else:
        with nostdout():
            ampl.solve()

    if False:
        bD = ampl.getParameter('B').getValues().toDict()
        qD = ampl.getParameter('q').getValues().toDict()
        xD = ampl.getVariable('x').getValues().toDict()
        BB = ampl.getParameter('B').getValues().toPandas().values.reshape((n, n,), order='C')
        qq = ampl.getParameter('q').getValues().toPandas().values[:, 0]
        xx = ampl.getVariable('x').getValues().toPandas().values[:, 0]
        ineq2 = BB.dot(xx) + qq
        print((xx * ineq2).min(), (xx * ineq2).max() )
    return ampl.getVariable('x').getValues().toPandas().values[:, 0]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # solve problem from the Julia port at https://github.com/chkwon/PATHSolver.jl
    n = 4
    B = np.array([[0, 0, -1, -1], [0, 0, 1, -2], [1, -1, 2, -2], [1, 2, -2, 4]])
    q = np.array([2, 2, -2, -6])

    BSparse = sparse.lil_matrix(B)

    env = Environment(binaryDirectory='/home/foo/amplide.linux64/')
    print(solveLCP(B, q, env=env))
    print(solveLCP(BSparse, q, env=env))

    # to test licensing
    from numpy import random
    n = 1000
    B = np.diag((random.randn(n)))
    q = np.ones((n,))
    print(solveLCP(B, q, env=env))
```